# Given n samples from a uniform distribution [0,d], how would you estimate d?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, statistics, distribution

I believe there are two approaches to solving this problem.

One would be to take the **MAX** from the sample set and the other would be to take **2 x the sample mean**.

I found a solution online that attempted to create these distribution to compare the two however, it was written unusually (for statements followed the actual statement). I attempted to rewrite it but something about my code is off. It doesn't seem like it is running the function multiple times and comparing the result as the sample size increases. Any help is appreciated.

My code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sample_random_normal(n = 100):
    for i in range(1,100):
        for j in [np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int)]:
            return np.array([np.array([max(j), 2*np.mean(j)])])

def repeat_experiment():
    for _ in range(1,100):
        experiments = np.array([sample_random_normal()])
        return experiments.mean(axis = 0)

result = repeat_experiment()
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = ['max_value', '2*mean']
df['k'] = pd.Series(range(1,100))
df['actual_value'] = 100
df['max_value-actual-value'] = df['max_value'] - df['actual_value']
df['2*mean-actual_value'] = df['2*mean'] - df['actual_value']
plt.plot(df['k'], df['max_value'], linestyle = 'solid', label = 'max_value_estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['2*mean'], linestyle = 'dashed', label = '2*mean estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['max_value-actual-value'], linestyle = 'solid', label = 'max_value_estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['2*mean-actual_value'], linestyle = 'dashed', label = '2*mean estimate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Original Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sample_random_normal(n = 100):
    return np.array([np.array([max(j), 2*np.mean(j)]) for j in [np.random.uniform(0, n, size=i).astype(int) for i in range(1, 100)]])

def repeat_experiment():
    experiments = np.array([sample_random_normal() for _ in range(100)])
    return experiments.mean(axis = 0)

result = repeat_experiment()
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = ['max_value', '2*mean']
df['k'] = range(1, 100)
df['actual_value'] = 100
df['max_value-actual-value'] = df['max_value'] - df['actual_value']
df['2*mean-actual-value'] = df['2*mean'] - df['actual_value']
plt.plot(df['k'], df['max_value'], linestyle='solid', label='max_value_estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['2*mean'], linestyle='dashed', label ='2*mean estimate')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at here:

```
def sample_random_normal(n = 100):
    for i in range(1,100):
        for j in [np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int)]:
            return np.array([np.array([max(j), 2*np.mean(j)])])
```

For the first `i`and `j` in your range, your function finds a return statement and stops. A correction would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sample_random_normal(n = 100):
        samples = [np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int) for i in range(1,100)]
        return np.array([np.array([max(j), 2*np.mean(j)]) for j in samples])

def repeat_experiment():
        experiments = np.array([sample_random_normal() for _ in range(100)])
        return experiments.mean(axis = 0)

result = repeat_experiment()
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = ['max_value', '2*mean']
df['k'] = pd.Series(range(1,100))
df['actual_value'] = 100
df['max_value-actual-value'] = df['max_value'] - df['actual_value']
df['2*mean-actual_value'] = df['2*mean'] - df['actual_value']
plt.plot(df['k'], df['max_value'], linestyle = 'solid', label = 'max_value_estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['2*mean'], linestyle = 'dashed', label = '2*mean estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['max_value-actual-value'], linestyle = 'solid', label = 'max_value-actual-value')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['2*mean-actual_value'], linestyle = 'dashed', label = '2*mean-actual_value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And the results are:

[image]

And you just showed these two estimators are consistent. Notice, however, that the maximum estimator is not unbiased, where 2 times the mean is. This is more of a math/statistic question, however; if interested, see [this question from math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246222/unbiased-estimator-of-a-uniform-distribution).

Besides, I fixed your legends, as they were wrong before.

Comment: Thank you! Quick question however, putting the for before or after the statement makes no difference? @econbernando

Comment: I don't understand the question, which statement are you referring to?

Comment: for example: `samples = [np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int) for i in range(1,100)]` the same as `for i in range(1,100): samples = [np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int)`

Comment: Please see above @econbernardo https://stackoverflow.com/users/15663290/econbernardo

Comment: Not, it's not the same. In the first case, you are creating a list comprehension: every element of this list comprehension is a numpy array of random uniforms of size `i`, where `i`varies. In the second case, you are making a loop on `i`, and at each iteration, **substituting** your variable `samples` by a list containing an array of realizations from a uniform distribution of size `i`. Instead of doing `samples = [np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int)`you should do `samples.append(np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int))` after creating an empty list `samples = []`before.

Comment: You should add `max(j)*(1 + 1/len(j)) - 1` as a third option, it's the min variance unbiased estimator of d for sample sizes > 1.

Comment: how would you do something similar for the array `return np.array([np.array([max(j), 2*np.mean(j)]) for j in samples]) ` ? @econbernardo

Answer (score 1):

There is a third solution which is better than your two proposed approaches. As pointed out by pavel in a comment, the allies used this to estimate how many tanks the Germans had produced in WWII. Using the maximum value observed yields a biased estimate, while doubling the average has high variability—scaling a random variable (the sample mean) by a factor of 2 quadruples the variance.

The solution derived by both frequentists and Bayesian statisticians is to scale the maximum observed value. Using your notation where `n` is the sample size, `d` is the population maximum, and `max` is the largest observed value, the estimator `max * (1 + 1/n) - 1` is the minimum variance unbiased estimate of `d` for sample sizes > 1. Since econbernardo has opted not to update their answer to include this, I'm adding it here.

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sample_random_normal(n = 100):
        samples = [np.random.uniform(0, n, size = i).astype(int) for i in range(1,100)]
        return np.array([np.array([max(j), max(j)*(1 + 1/len(j)) - 1, 2*np.mean(j)]) for j in samples])

def repeat_experiment():
        experiments = np.array([sample_random_normal() for _ in range(100)])
        return experiments.mean(axis = 0)

result = repeat_experiment()
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = ['max_value', 'unbiased_max', '2*mean']
df['k'] = pd.Series(range(1,100))
df['actual_value'] = 100
df['max_value-actual-value'] = df['max_value'] - df['actual_value']
df['unbiased_max-actual-value'] = df['unbiased_max'] - df['actual_value']
df['2*mean-actual_value'] = df['2*mean'] - df['actual_value']
plt.plot(df['k'], df['max_value'], linestyle = 'dotted', label = 'max_value_estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['unbiased_max'], linestyle = 'solid', label = 'unbiased_max_estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['2*mean'], linestyle = 'dashed', label = '2*mean estimate')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['max_value-actual-value'], linestyle = 'dotted', label = 'max_value-actual-value')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['unbiased_max-actual-value'], linestyle = 'solid', label = 'unbiased_max-actual-value')
plt.plot(df['k'], df['2*mean-actual_value'], linestyle = 'dashed', label = '2*mean-actual_value')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

A sample plot of the results is given below. The solid lines are the unbiased MVUE based on the observed max, the other two are from your proposed solutions.

[image: Plot of three estimators]

As you can see, the scaled max estimator dominates the performance of the other two, lacking the bias of the vanilla max and having less variability than doubling the sample mean.